# Make UIButton image appear crisp-perfect on retina display

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage

So I've done lots of reading on how to achieve perfect image quality on UIButton's .imageView property in iOS. Here's my example ->

I've got an UIButton 24x24 points as per the following line:

```
myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(82, 8, 24, 24);
myButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
ogImage = [buttonImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

I then have the original image sized to 46x46 pixels (twice 23x23, 24x24 on button for even size to prevent iOS auto-aliasing), then the image@2x at 92x92 pixels. Im testing on an iPhone 6s (obviously retina display) and am still seeing some jaggedness on my UIButton's image. What am I doing wrong here? Am I still not understanding how to achieve perfect retina quality?

Here's an image, Im hoping it displays well for example:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the content mode of the button's `imageView`? That is, `myButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is going to help, but this is my personal preference. If for example, I have a UIButoon of size 24x24, I always generate 24x24, 48x48, and 72x72 images. I rely on my Adobe Illustrator to creat pixel perfect images. Always check your images in pixel preview mode and make sure edges are aligned with the pixels. If not, it can produce artifacts that you see in xCode.
If it's what you want in Illustrator then it's what you get in xCode.